# Installing additional Java dependencies to react-native library

Tags: java, android, react-native

I want to bring more functionality to an existing `react-native` library - namely to [react-native-maps](https://github.com/react-community/react-native-maps). In order to do that, I have to add an [additional Java library](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Database_Connectivity). No I wonder where exactly am I supposed to add the Java library. Do I add here (in a newly created `lib` folder)
https://github.com/react-community/react-native-maps/tree/master/lib/android or somewhere else? How do I make it "known" to Java?

Answer (score 2):

I think you mean with "Java" your IDE. Depends on what IDE you're using if you happen to use

**IntelliJ** it goes as follows:

1. Click `File` from the toolbar
2. Project Structure (<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> on Windows/Linux, <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>;</kbd> on Mac OS X)
3. Select Modules at the left panel
4. Dependencies tab
5. '+' → JARs or directories

**Eclipse**

1. Start Eclipse, and locate the project folder to which the library
   should be added.
2. Right-click this class folder, and select "Properties"
3. Select "Java Build Path" on the left, and then the "Libraries" tab.
   Now, click the "Add External JARS..." button
4. Locate and select the `.jar` file you just downloaded, and then
   click "Open"
5. Finally, click "OK" to close the dialog box.

**Netbeans**

1. In the Projects window right-click on the name of the project
2. Click Properties, The Project Properties window opens.
3. In the categories tree select "Libraries"
4. On the right side of the Project Properties window press button "Add
   JAR/Folder"

Comment: not quite. when you look at the setup of `react-native-maps`, there are several `.gradle` and I am unsure in which place the library needs to be added...

Answer (score 1):

In the case of Gradle you should edit the `build.gradle` file located at the root of the project. In that file under the section `dependency`.

**Copy From Source**

[Gradle Guide Android Studio 'Adding dependencies'](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies.html)

Local binary dependency

```
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
```

Because Gradle reads paths relative to the build.gradle file, this tells the build system to add all JAR files inside your project's `module_name/libs/` directory as dependencies.

Alternatively, you specify individual files as follows:

```
compile files('libs/foo.jar', 'libs/bar.jar')
```

**Example**

```
dependencies {
  def googlePlayServicesVersion = rootProject.hasProperty('googlePlayServicesVersion')  ? rootProject.googlePlayServicesVersion : DEFAULT_GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION
  def androidMapsUtilsVersion   = rootProject.hasProperty('androidMapsUtilsVersion')    ? rootProject.androidMapsUtilsVersion   : DEFAULT_ANDROID_MAPS_UTILS_VERSION

  compileOnly "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"
  compile files('libs/name_of_library.jar') //<----- added external library for gradle to build
  implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:$googlePlayServicesVersion"
  implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:$googlePlayServicesVersion"
  implementation "com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:$androidMapsUtilsVersion"
}
```